# Spacy and Sense2vec are not compatible

Tags: python-2.7, spacy, sense2vec

Installing **[sense2vec](https://github.com/explosion/sense2vec)** rolls back `spacy` version to `0.101.0`. None of the current English `spacy` models are compatible with `0.101.0` and raises this error when trying to load:
`super(Package, self).__init__(defaults=meta['package']) KeyError: 'package'`.

After upgrading `spacy` version, `sense2vec`(`0.6.0`) does not load. It is throwing `ValueError: spacy.strings.StringStore has the wrong size`.

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I figured a way to use both spacy and sense2vec. I installed spacy on python3, and sense2vec on python2.